# Command prompt script to subtract variables

Tags: batch-file, math

I know there are many arithmetic questions on here, but I have not found the specific answer to my question.  I have a file with two values in it, the first always higher than the second.  Today, the txt file has:

```
21.04
20.94
```

What I am trying to do is, via a batch file, subtract the second number from the first, and then insert than on a new line.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Batch file only does integer maths. So no decimals.

Comment: Is there a known pattern with the number of digits, before and/or after the decimal point, character lengths etc.? Having a known pattern would make it a more realistic consideration to not opt for utility assistance.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Hm okay.  The first number will always be larger than the second, and both will always have two decimal places.  However, the number starts off at 0.00 on Jan 1 (rainfall totals) and could conceivably go over 100.00 (most rain we have ever had in a year was 80" or so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incorporate `powershell` into the batch file.

to test from `cmd`:

```
@for /f %i in ('powershell 21.04 - 20.94') do @echo %i
```

So you can build a very basic calculator rather easily.

```
set /p "first=Enter first number: "
set /p "second=Enter Second Number: "
set /p "function=Select Function(+-/): "
powershell %first% %function% %second%
```

And offcourse you can use a `for` loop to assign the value to a variable should you want to use it elsewhere in your batch file.

```
@echo off
set /p "first=Enter first number: "
set /p "second=Enter Second Number: "
set /p "function=Select Function(+-/): "
for /f %%i in ('powershell %first% %function% %second%') do set "result=%%i"
echo %result%
```

in a `batch-file` you double the `%` in meta variables to `%%i`

Assuming file is called `math.txt`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cnt=1
for /f "usebackq" %%i in ("d:\math.txt") do (
   set var!cnt!=%%i
   set /a cnt+=1
)
(powershell %var1% - %var2%)>output.txt
pause
```

Comment: Gerhard, I may be missing it, but using your code, how to do I get it to read the two ever-changing values from the txt file?  The filename will always be the same, FYI, only the values change.

Comment: well, I did not show reading from file as the question was about calculation issues using `batch-file`

Comment: Got it to work by changing "usbackq" to "useback".  It returns the answer in the cmd window.  How can I redirect it out to a file (original or new, doesn't matter).

Comment: `(powershell %var1% - %var2%)>output.txt` also update in answer.

Comment: There is no `useback` option, @sbagnato, it is `usebackq`, it just so happens that shortening it by removing the last character works too because it is corrected to `usebackq` internally by the parser. There is absolutely no reason why the latter would work if the former fails.

Comment: Do you know that **powershell.exe** is a 441 Kb size file? That is 1.6 times the size of **cmd.exe**! Using powershell for a task as simple as a subtraction is like using a mallet to kill a mosquito. There are [native Batch-file ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62915017/778560) to do the same...

Comment: @Aacini. Yes, but the functions are built-in to **powershell** and not into **cmd**, meaning we have to write bunches of code to hack through the numbers to get a result, where powershell it is a matter providing numbers and function. I have written similar native `batch-files` but this is a much simpler method... PS!!Nice method you used!!

Comment: Gerhard, how would I update `(powershell %var1% - %var2%) > .....` to round the result to two decimal places?  I tried to implement `[math]::Round` but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

This method works with numbers up to 9 total digits (and any number of decimals) as long as the input numbers have *the same number* of decimals:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read two numbers
( set /P "num1=" & set /P "num2=" ) < test.txt

rem Adjust *two* numbers for given decimals
set "decimals=2"
for %%i in (1 2) do (
   set "num%%i=!num%%i:.=!"
   for /L %%d in (1,1,%decimals%) do if "!num%%i:~0,1!" equ "0" set "num%%i=!num%%i:~1!"
)

rem Subtract second number from the first
set /A "result=num1 - num2"

rem Adjust result for given number of decimals
for /L %%d in (1,1,%decimals%) do if "!result:~%decimals%!" equ "" set "result=0!result!"

rem Output result with decimals
echo !result:~0,-%decimals%!.!result:~-%decimals%!
```

Comment: I tested your solution and I like it. However, how do I output to file? It isn't as simple as > "C:\CumulusMX\cocorahs_reports\output.txt"...

Comment: @sbagnato: Did you tested it? Just put the redirection _before_ the `echo` command...

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for reasonably sized numbers:

```
@echo off

rem read values from file specified as command line parameter    
(
    set /p value1=
    set /p value2=
)<%1

rem split first value into whole and fractional parts
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%value1%") do (
    set beforedot1=%%a
    set afterdot1=%%b
)

rem reconstruct first value as fixed point number
set afterdot1=%afterdot1%00000
set afterdot1=%afterdot1:~0,6%
set value1=%beforedot1%%afterdot1%

rem split second value into whole and fractional parts
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%value2%") do (
    set beforedot2=%%a
    set afterdot2=%%b
)

rem reconstruct second value as fixed point number
set afterdot2=%afterdot2%00000
set afterdot2=%afterdot2:~0,6%
set value2=%beforedot2%%afterdot2%

rem subtract values
set /a diff=value1-value2

rem convert fixed point value back
if "%diff:~0,-6%" == "" (
    set diff=0.%diff:~-6%
) else (
    set diff=%diff:~0,-6%.%diff:~-6%
)

rem remove trailing zeros
:loop
if "%diff:~-1%" == "0" (
    set diff=%diff:~0,-1%
    goto :loop
)

echo %diff%
```